# Border-radius not working properly on Safari and on iPhone devices?

Tags: html, safari

I am applying `border-radius` on an icon. The icon looks fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. However, the icon shape slightly changes on Safari or an other Apple devices. Here is picture of icon on chrome

[image]

and Safari

[image]

. How can I make the icon look consistent on all devices and web browsers? Here is the CSS:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-bus fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="bus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M488 128h-8V80c0-44.8-99.2-80-224-80S32 35.2 32 80v48h-8c-13.25 0-24 10.74-24 24v80c0 13.25 10.75 24 24 24h8v160c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32v32c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h32c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32v-32h192v32c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h32c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32v-32h6.4c16 0 25.6-12.8 25.6-25.6V256h8c13.25 0 24-10.75 24-24v-80c0-13.26-10.75-24-24-24zM112 400c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32s14.33-32 32-32 32 14.33 32 32-14.33 32-32 32zm16-112c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32V128c0-17.67 14.33-32 32-32h256c17.67 0 32 14.33 32 32v128c0 17.67-14.33 32-32 32H128zm272 112c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32s14.33-32 32-32 32 14.33 32 32-14.33 32-32 32z"></path></svg>

.fa-bus{
    background: #0046add;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 9px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Remove **Padding** and then try maybe it works!

Comment: @Aman No, that doesn't work. Plus, I need to keep that padding.

Comment: can you show your full SVG code so i can check

Comment: @Aman That's pretty much the full SVG. I think the problem is with the `Border-Radius'.

Comment: I mean I have to check on my end what's the issue with border-radius that's why I'm asking for SVG side

Comment: you have shown only SVG tag provide path etc. code

Comment: @Aman I have added the full SVG html.

Comment: You have to use an outer div and implement CSS on that check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an outer div and implement CSS on that

```css
.svg_icon{
    background: #0046dd;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 9px;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.svg_icon svg{
    color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg_icon">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-bus fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="bus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M488 128h-8V80c0-44.8-99.2-80-224-80S32 35.2 32 80v48h-8c-13.25 0-24 10.74-24 24v80c0 13.25 10.75 24 24 24h8v160c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32v32c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h32c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32v-32h192v32c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h32c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32v-32h6.4c16 0 25.6-12.8 25.6-25.6V256h8c13.25 0 24-10.75 24-24v-80c0-13.26-10.75-24-24-24zM112 400c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32s14.33-32 32-32 32 14.33 32 32-14.33 32-32 32zm16-112c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32V128c0-17.67 14.33-32 32-32h256c17.67 0 32 14.33 32 32v128c0 17.67-14.33 32-32 32H128zm272 112c-17.67 0-32-14.33-32-32s14.33-32 32-32 32 14.33 32 32-14.33 32-32 32z"></path></svg</div>
```